# Different forms display on same page when clicked on different buttons using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, button

I have two buttons say CITIZEN and POLICE. When I click on the button CITIZEN, I want to display a form say CITIZEN_FORM on the same page. And when I click on the button POLICE, I want to display a form say POLICE_FORM on the same page.

How to do this using JavaScript and HTML?

Comment: give ids to form of citizen and police and apply hide/show event on button click. Search for hide/show div using javascript.

Comment: Do you want to show only one or the other, or both in some cases?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

HTML:-

```
<form id = "policeForm" action="" style="display:none">
  <input type="submit" value="Police Form">
</form>
<form id = "citizenForm" action="" style="display:none">
  <input type="submit" value="Citizen Form">
</form>
<button id= "citizenBtn" onclick="showForm('citizenForm')">citizen</button>
<button id="police" onclick="showForm('policeForm')">police</button>
```

Javascript

```
var showForm = function(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = '';
}
```

Comment: @RobG I thought about that but after that I thought it could be tricky. anyway I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?:

```
<script>
    $("input").click(function(){
        var mode = $(this).val();
        if(mode == "citizen"){
            $("#form_citizen").css("display", "block");
            $("#form_police").css("display", "none");
        }else if (mode == "police"){
            $("#form_citizen").css("display", "none");
            $("#form_police").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
</script>


<div id="panel">
    <input type="button" name="citizen" value="citizen" />
    <input type="button" name="police" value="police" />
</div>

<form id="form_police">....</form>
<form id="form_citizen">...</form>
```

But actually stackoverflow is not a "I-don't-know-how-to-write-my-code-please-do-it-for-me" website.
You should try it yourself and if you fail, we help.

I just coded a short help, using jQuery to handle stylings.

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a simple  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qde8/1/).

Just hid the forms to begin with, and add event listeners to your buttons to show the form in question. Here I hide the buttons after they're clicked, because that seems to make sense for this kind of application...

HTML:

```
<button id="a">Form A</button><button id="b">Form B</button>
<form id="a_form" name="a" style="display:none;">
    <input name="a_input" value="A: type here"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<form id="b_form" name="b" style="display:none;">
    <input name="b_input" value="B: type here"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var a=document.getElementById('a');
var b=document.getElementById('b');
a.addEventListener('click',function(){
    a.style.display="none";
    b.style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('a_form').style.display="";
});
b.addEventListener('click',function(){
    a.style.display="none";
    b.style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('b_form').style.display="";
});
```